# Ionic ionViewDidEnter from Ionic Creator export

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm an Ionic newb, and I can't seem to figure this out. I created a project in Ionic Creator, then exported the Zip. Now I've got the `controller.js`, `services.js` files, etc, but they don't look anything like the sample sources that are in the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#action-sheets

When I try to find samples, I see stuff like https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/src/pages/action-sheets/basic but the code conforms to what is in the documentation.

For instance, the exports have things like this from `controllers.js`:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('page1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
```

While sample code is built out like classes:

```
import { ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {

  constructor(public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) { }
```

**So the question:**
How would I go about using `ionViewDidEnter` in the structure of an Ionic Creator export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your problem.
What is happening is that you have created a project in Ionic Creator of Ionic version 1.x (1.3.2).
Ionic 1 is based on Angular 1.x, and Ionic 2 is based on Angular >= 2.x. With Ionic 1 you will see controller.js, services.js and files like that. With Ionic 2/3, you will see classes, components, and stuff like that.

You need to select the Ionic version before you [start creating your design with Ionic creator](https://creator.ionic.io/app/dashboard/projects).

[image]